# redirection 301 with specials caracteres

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

i have old url like :

```
http://example.fr/fr-cuisines+et+salles+bains.html
```

And i would rewrite it like :

```
https://www.example.fr/cuisines-salles-de-bains/
```

I have try that but it doesn't work ???

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.fr (it's working no problem)
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.example.fr [R=301,L] (it's working no problem)
RewriteRule ^fr-cuisines+et+salles+bains$ cuisines-salles-de-bains/ [R=301,NC,L] (Not working)
```

Comment: The `+` characters have already been decoded to spaces in the URL path that RewriteRule matches against. And you will probably have to change the order of those rules, otherwise `^/?(.*)$` will catch this already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution :

```
RewriteRule ^fr-cuisines\+et\+salles\+bains\.html$ /cuisines-salles-de-bains/ [R=301,L]
```